# How to increment version number using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a version number with three columns and two digits (`xx:xx:xx`). Can anyone please tell me how to increment that using shell script.

```
Min Value
00:00:00

Max Value
99:99:99

Sample IO
10:23:56 -> 10:23:57
62:54:99 -> 62:55:00
87:99:99 -> 88:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

As a one liner using awk, assuming VERSION is a variable with the version in it:

```
echo $VERSION | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { $3++;  if ($3 > 99) { $3=0; $2++; if ($2 > 99) { $2=0; $1++ } } } { printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing fancy (other than Bash) needed:

```
$ ver=87:99:99
$ echo "$ver"
87:99:99
$ printf -v ver '%06d' $((10#${ver//:}+1))
$ ver=${ver%????}:${ver: -4:2}:${ver: -2:2}
$ echo "$ver"
88:00:00
```

We just use the parameter expansion `${ver//:}` to remove the colons: we're then left with a usual decimal number, increment it and reformat it using `printf`; then use some more parameter expansions to group the digits.

This assumes that `ver` has already been thorougly checked (with a regex or glob).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just needs some little math tricks and `bc` command, here is how:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read VERSION from $1 into VER
IFS=':' read -r -a VER <<< "$1"

# increment by 1
INCR=$(echo "ibase=10; ${VER[0]}*100*100+${VER[1]}*100+${VER[2]}+1"|bc)

# prepend zeros
INCR=$(printf "%06d" ${INCR})

# output the result
echo ${INCR:0:2}:${INCR:2:2}:${INCR:4:2}
```

If you need overflow checking you can do it with the trick like `INCR` statement.

Comment: Doesn't work if major version number is < 10, e.g., `09:00:00`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yeah, it improved :)

Answer (score 0):

This basically works, but may or may not do string padding:

```
IN=43:99:99
F1=`echo $IN | cut -f1 '-d:'`
F2=`echo $IN | cut -f2 '-d:'`
F3=`echo $IN | cut -f3 '-d:'`

F3=$(( F3 + 1 ))
if [ "$F3" -gt 99 ] ; then F3=00 ; F2=$(( F2 + 1 )) ; fi
if [ "$F2" -gt 99 ] ; then F2=00 ; F1=$(( F1 + 1 )) ; fi

OUT="$F1:$F2:$F3"
echo $OUT
```

Comment: You can use `IFS=: read -r F1 F2 F3 <<< "$IN"` instead of using `cut` to split `$IN`.

Comment: @andlrc Cool!  I did not know about the Internal Field Separator in bash.

Comment: This needs some work to handle leading zeros, both restoring them after the arithmetic and avoiding base-8 arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

try this  one liner:

```
awk '{gsub(/:/,"");$0++;gsub(/../,"&:");sub(/:$/,"")}7'
```

tests:

```
kent$  awk '{gsub(/:/,"");$0++;gsub(/../,"&:");sub(/:$/,"")}7' <<< "22:33:99"
22:34:00

kent$  awk '{gsub(/:/,"");$0++;gsub(/../,"&:");sub(/:$/,"")}7' <<< "22:99:99"
23:00:00

kent$  awk '{gsub(/:/,"");$0++;gsub(/../,"&:");sub(/:$/,"")}7' <<< "22:99:88"
22:99:89
```

Note, corner cases were not tested.